# Improve memory consumption of a map of tuples without losing speed in C++

Tags: c++, performance, memory, dictionary, tuples

In order to store costs for 5-tuples, I have a map as follows:

```
std::map<std::tr1::tuple<u32, u32, u32, u32, u8>, f32> costsMap_;
```

There are several such tables to be loaded into memory during runtime, where each has approx. 2.5*10⁷ entries. Each entry has the form

```
2.16345 # 5875 396 # 47512 26445 # 2
```

and is read from disk using an `std::inputstream`. Afterwards, the entries remain unchanged.

Many of the tuples differ only in 1 value, i.e. there are many values that appear in quite a few entries. I thought about making use of this fact and not storing values unnecessarily often.

I have tried a sequence of maps of maps like

```
std::map<u32, std::map<u32, std::map<u32, std::map<u32, std::map<u8,f32>>>>> costsMap_;
```

but this is too slow, because there are millions of look-ups in only a few minutes and therefore the look-up has to be reasonably fast as well (it's not fully optimized towards runtime yet).

Is there a way to load the tables into memory, such that the memory consumption goes down significantly (at least by a factor of 2) without losing too much speed during runtime at the same time?

Comment: Do you need to modify the maps after loading? Sorted vector and binary search might be a good choice if not.

Comment: Also, if you have the time, check out the [boost flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: No, after loading the maps they remain unchanged. Why does a sorted vector need less memory?

Comment: Consider [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) if you don't want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Sorted vectors could achieve the same time complexity as map on lookup operations, while the data locality is much better since all data resides on consecutive space. Furthermore, sorted vectors does not require those pointers forming binary search tree inside map for each element.

Comment: @FKaria: "Why does a sorted vector need less memory?" `map` is typically implemented as a search tree, with quite a bit of overhead per node; looking at GCC's implementation, each node contains 3 pointers and a flag, as well as the key/value pair. On a 64-bit platform, that overhead is more than the amount of data stored. `vector` simply stores the elements in an array of contiguous memory, with no overhead apart from that necessary for alignment.

Comment: If the range of values of each item in the tuples is sparse, using a hash table might help.

Comment: Does `std::map<u32, std::map<u32, std::map<u32, std::map<u32, std::map<u8,f32>>>>> costsMap_;` give you the desired savings in memory, i.e. the slowdown is your only concern with that change?

Comment: How do you populate the map? Is the data coming from a SQL database on which you can perform `ORDER BY ...`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Initially, I used the even more naive implementation of using maps of maps ... of maps. At that time, I had to process less data, i.e. the memory consumption was not an issue. Nevertheless, it was too slow, such that I re-implemented it as a map of tuples, which solved the time complexity problem. Now that I'm processing larger data, I've run into memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the overlap by splitting the tuple at the length of the most common prefix, rather than splitting it at each level.

For example, let's say that your data has a large number of overlap on the first three members of the tuple, i.e. if you consider only the first three members of each tuple in the map, the number of distinct entries drops a couple of orders of magnitude. In that case you can split the map into a map of maps. I also suggest using `unordered_map`, because it's asymptotically faster.

```
std::unordered_map<std::tr1::tuple<u32,u32,u32>,std::unordered_map<std::tr1::tuple<u32,u8>,f32> > costsMap_;
```

This approach reduces duplication of the key storage at the cost of additional lookup. It results in savings only when the number of duplication among the prefixes of the tuples that you store is high enough to justify the additional lookup.

Observe that this approach is a generalization of the map expansion approach that you have suggested in your post, with the first three and the last two positions "fused" into tuples. You can choose other points for the split - for example, if the first four keys are often duplicated you could use

```
std::unordered_map<std::tr1::tuple<u32,u32,u32,u32>,std::unordered_map<u8,f32> > costsMap_;
```

with all but the last lookup keys "fused" into a tuple.